# Emacs: how to bind a key tapped twice?

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs (23) and I am binding the `C-.` key combination to a function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'myfunction)
```

Is it possible to bind a quick "double tap" of a key? For example, I would like to call a function `myfunction` when typing `.` quickly two times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't anything built in, but you can use this code.  Customize the variables `dc-single-click-cmd` and `dc-double-click-cmd` to be the commands you want.

Note: this introduces a slight delay, b/c the code needs to wait for a little bit of time to determine whether the event was a single or double click.

```
(defvar dc-single-click-cmd 'dc-example-single-click)
(defvar dc-double-click-cmd 'dc-example-double-click)
(defvar dc-click-timer nil
  "Pending single-click event.")
(defun dc-example-single-click ()
  (interactive)
  (message "A single click just happened."))
(defun dc-example-double-click ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Wait!  I meant double click."))
(defun dc-click-cmd ()
  "Either kick off a single click, or a double click."
  (interactive)
  (if dc-click-timer
      (progn
        (cancel-timer dc-click-timer)
        (setq dc-click-timer nil)
        (call-interactively dc-double-click-cmd))
    (setq dc-click-timer (run-at-time (when double-click-time 
                                            (/ 1000.0 double-click-time))
                                      nil
                                      'dc-call-single-click))))
(defun dc-call-single-click ()
  "spawn the single click"
  (setq dc-click-timer nil)
  (call-interactively dc-single-click-cmd))
```

Comment: Thank you Trey, I tried that and it works nicely. Rethinking my problem over the night I think that it would be also interesting if I could customize the input-method: when writing a `'`, for example, emacs will wait the for the next character and modify the buffer contents (`'a` will result in `á`). This however, is the topic of another question that I might ask later, after I do my own research.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [KeyChord](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) is the canonical solution to this nowadays.

(Disclaimer: I don't use KeyChord myself (yet), but many people do, so I am certain it is at least worth trying.)

Answer (score 0):

(defun myfunction2 ()
  (interactive)
  (if (not (eq last-command 'myfunction2))
      (insert ".")
    (setq this-command  nil)
    (delete-backward-char 1)
    (call-interactively 'myfunction)))

(defun myfunction ()
  (interactive)
  (message "MYFUNCTION"))

(global-set-key "." 'myfunction2)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/k-talo/double-type.el offers similar functionality to what you are looking for.